# Ribbon menu in IPad application

Tags: ios, ipad, menu

I want to use ribbon menu(as on Microsoft Word 2007 or 10) in my IPad application. Anyone have any suggestions? If it impossible to implement, may be anyone have other ideas how to implement similar functionality? In IOS development i am newbie, so i can not imagine how to modulate Ribbon menu with Xcode tools. May be using of Ribbon menu in tablet Apps is not good idea, if so, what alternative i can use? Ribbon menu need because application is very large, and it's have many tools and options. Thanks!:)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid the Ribbon. I am pretty sure it wasn't designed for touch and users will reject the idea of such a distinctive Windows control on iOS. There are other options for complicated  options than a Ribbon. Google iPad menu.